# Collection View Not Scrolling, inside container view

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a container view, which holds a collection view that works correctly when on another page and not in the container. An embed segue is called initially and the collection view shows correctly, however, the scrolling will not work at all. I have looked around for an answer but cannot seem to find anything at all. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Is your container view a scrollview or scrollable in any way? If so, the scrollview might be "eating up" all the touch events

Comment: No the container view isn't scrollable in any way. I do have a swipe gesture on it, which I thought may have been "eating up" the touch events, however I removed the swipe gesture and it still does not seem to be scroll. Is there any way I can test if it is even recognising an attempt to scroll?

Comment: Thanks for the reply by the way, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here. So if you present the view controller that manages the collection view, it works fine, but when you embed the view in a containerview, it doesn't work? Could you try logging something whenever the view controller receives touch events to check if it is receiving any touch events at all?

Comment: Will give it a go and let you know the outcome, one second.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that even didSelectItemAtIndexPath is not registering when I select a cell from the collection view.

Comment: connect the delegate

Comment: You can try to implement

`gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`

and return YES

Comment: solved? any solutions?